How to use --fission in Bazel
I'm trying to use the --fission Bazel command line option to generate a binary with separate debug information in a Linux C++ project using the default GCC toolchain.
I don't see any difference when I build with or without --fission.
I'm using the hello-world example from the Bazel C++ tutorial and Bazel version 7.2.1.
I'm trying build commands like:
bazel build -c dbg --fission=yes //main:hello-world

using different compilation modes and --fission values, but the file with the debug symbols is not generated.
I found a similar problem on GitHub, but it seems to be solved and none of the workarounds worked for me.

Probably the problem is in the configuration of the aspect_gcc_toolchain, the fully-hermetic Bazel GCC toolchain used in the Bazel tutorials. The option --fission works as expected using the default system gcc, removing the toolchain configuration from the WORKSPACE.
